# What is a set with a function $f$ that don't satisfy peano's axioms?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

I'm reading "classic set theory for guided independent study", and i'm studying the construction of natural numbers using peano's axioms.

The three axioms they give me are:
A Peano system is a set $X$ with a special element $0∈X$ and a funtion $S:X→X$ such that the following also hold:

1. The function S is one-one
2. For all $x∈X$, $0≠S(x)$
3. For all subset $A⊆X$, if A contains $0$ and contains $S(x)$ whenever $x∈A$, then $A$ is all of $X$.

I can't come up with any set and function that doesn't satisfy them, you guys have any idea?

Comment: I mean, out of the seven true/false combinations of $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ such that not all three are true, a few are fairly easy.

Comment: How about $X$ is the reals, and $S(x)=x^2$?

Comment: $X = \{ 0 \}$ and $S(0)=0$.

Comment: How about $\mathbb Z /p\mathbb Z$. This violates $0\ne S(x)$

Comment: A simple example violating all three conditions at once is the constant $0$ function on $X=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satisfying 1 and 2: $X=\Bbb N_0$, $S(x)=x+2$

Satisfying 1 and 3: $X=\{0,1\}$, $S(x)=1-x$

Satisfying 2 and 3: $X=\{0,1\}$, $S(x)=1$